# Why do you use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect to create a new history object in BrowserRouter?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I looked at some of the source code, but I had some problems in them. It should be here - [BrowserRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/7dca9dc38c837ed94796325b1e0582aa72a9313f/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L158), Why do you use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect to create a new history object in BrowserRouter? If you have free time, can you solve my puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem one time. I hope can help you. useLayoutEffect is synchronized with the screen. It prevent visual bug during refreshing.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).